# How to secure a video file played through Media Source Extension API?

Tags: security, video, video-streaming, mpeg-dash, netflix

I have made a web video player using the Media Source Extension API. The video and audio my player downloads and plays is not secure. As in you can go to the `Network` in Google Chrome `Inspect` and download the video and audio and play it through a media player. I want to make my audio and video files to be played via my video player **only**.

A perfect secure video files example is here. The video player: http://reference.dashif.org/dash.js/nightly/samples/dash-if-reference-player/index.html. U can insert the source in the input: https://dash.akamaized.net/akamai/bbb_30fps/bbb_30fps.mpd. And when I download the files from `Network` in the Google Chrome `Inspect`, I cannot play the video file of `.m4v` in `VLC` or else where. So I think that this is secure. The files downloaded for playback can be found here: http://dash.akamaized.net/akamai/bbb_30fps/bbb_30fps_1280x720_4000k.

Netflix has very very secured video files where the file try isn't even defined. So can someone advise me how to secure my video and audio files to be downloaded and played from else where. Thanks

A sample of my video player project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/156mDgIltBGMkXhx4LZfShxv3A8JrwkNP/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The m4v files can be played, you just need to append them to the initialization fragment. Netflix does not use Media Source Extensions directly. They use Encrypted Media Extensions along with a DRM provider such as widevine.

Comment: Is there a demo available? I researched on Encrypted Media Extension, its really confusing.

Comment: Most open source players will support eme. That’s the best demo.

Comment: But where is the demo available? e.g. Media Source Extension demo is : http://nickdesaulniers.github.io/netfix/demo/bufferAll.html

Comment: Your google works the same as mine. There are blogs, specifications, open source examples, etc all available for free online. I don’t know what precisely you want in a “demo”.

Comment: I still can't make the video files secure like NetFlix. Is there a tutorial which clearly shows that?

Comment: DRM is a very complex system. It would take me more than a day too. Perhaps you may wish to contact a DRM provider such as BuyDRM for assistance.

Comment: True, DRM does seem complex. Can you tell me steps on making secure video files like YouTube's or like these: http://dash.akamaized.net/akamai/bbb_30fps/bbb_30fps_1280x720_4000k and how to use them with MSE?